# Number validation in range in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a project using AngularJS and I want to integrate validation in AngularJS. My requirement is that the number should be between the 1-4096 in AngularJS.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="VLAN ID" ng-model="exchange.vlanId" valid-number/>
</div>
```

Comment: Use simple comparison: `num >= 1 && num <= 4096` on blur/keyup event

Comment: Adding onto the answer @Tushar gave, check out the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D). There are provisions for min and max, which if crossed trigger an error.

Comment: `valid-number` Have you created a directive for it @Karan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create very simple directive that would allow to validate input in reusable, configurable and declarative way.

You already have `valid-number` attribute, so the implementation can look like:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).directive('validNumber', [function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;
            var range = attrs.validNumber.split(',').map(Number);
            ctrl.$validators.validNumber = function(value) {
                return value >= range[0] && value <= range[1];
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

```css
.error {color: brown;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo">
    
    <form name="form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="VLAN ID" name="vlanId"
               ng-model="exchange.vlanId" valid-number="1,4096" />
    </form>
    
    <div class="error" ng-show="form.$dirty && form.vlanId.$error.validNumber">VLAN ID should be in range 1-4096.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind an event on the input and call a function with passing the model in it:

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="VLAN ID" 
       ng-model="exchange.vlanId"
       ng-keydown="obj.validate(exchange.vlanId)" valid-number/>
```

Now in the controller you can define a method:

```
yourApp.controller('theController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.obj = {
        validate:function(val){
           if(val < 1 || val > 4096){
              alert(val+' is out of range');
           }
        }
    };
}]);
```

---

And the directive `valid-number` can also be used:

```
yourApp.directive('validNumber', function($scope){
    return {
       restrict:'E',
       link:function(scope, el, attrs){
          el.on('keydown', function(){
             el.css('border', function(){
               return  scope.exchange.vlanId < 1 || scope.exchange.vlanId > 4096
               ? "red" : "green";
             });
          });
       }
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you notice `valid-number` attribute?

Comment: The `valid-number` directive.

Comment: i see, that could also be used. hmmm... it was better to ask for it...:(